# javac current file code in vim file?

Tags: vim, javac

I want to source a vim file in vimrc file.
I wrote code in vim file.

```
set makeprg=javac %
```

and vim said he doesn't know that option.
how do i write code that javac current file?

what I want to do is compiling current file in vim while coding..

Comment: my os: windows 10, I tried javac %, javac \%...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command-line a space is used to separate 2 arguments. So, when you execute:

```
set makeprg=javac %
```

The `:set` command assigns the value `javac` to the option `'makeprg'`, then it tries to enable the option `'%'`, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

If you want the space to be included inside the value of the `'makeprg'` option, you need to escape it:

```
set makeprg=javac\ %
```